# Wi fi is not working after update

Tags: wireless, upgrade, 20.04, .desktop, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS version[image]

After Updated my machine I can't connect to Wi-Fi. Even if not shown in the bar or setting.
For this reason, I Completely format and reinstall the ubuntu 20.04 version. Then the same problem occurs after the update.[image]

Running `Uname-r`

```
Linux kasun 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ps: There is anyways to go back to a previous version or any other solution

Comment: If you hadn’t formatted, then you could have gone back to the 5.4 kernel quite easily. What you’ll need to do now is find an installation image that uses the previous 5.4 kernel and reinstall 

Comment: After formatted its working properly. That case also come after update the OS. Could I now GO to the previous version